# Spring Mongotemplate to fetch data from multiple collections

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-mongo

I have started working with spring and mongodb last few month ago.  Till now I din't get how to fetch data from multiple collection using Mongotemplate or MongoRepository.
     I have two collections user and address .now I want to fetch list of user along with address. 
So here how I can get the result in one query  for list of User and address data.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why any one not  giving comment on this question ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26865047/how-to-get-data-from-two-collections-in-spring-using-mongotemplate-or-mongorepos

Answer (score 2):

Use `DBRef`

```
public class User extends Entity {
  private String name;
  @DBRef
  private Address address;
  private String gender;
}
```

Then mongo in db create documents with links on another collection

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54b7937fe4b0b05ce14f03b8"), 
   "name" : null, 
   "address" : 
        { "$ref" : "address", "$id" : ObjectId("54b7937fe4b0b05ce14f0351") } 
}
```

and when you fetch data, mongodb will make it yourself

Comment: Outstanding response, I never knew that kind of lazy loading was even possible with mongo!